# Using in-memory storage for session data on a very small web application

Tags: node.js, web-development-server

I'm currently working on a very small web application for a small business. The work is almost exclusively front-end with a very minimal back-end (node.js). I want to implement basic flashing functionality for one of the pages on the website using connect-flash (https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-flash). This stores messages in the session and deletes these messages from the session after they are displayed.

I understand that in-memory session storage is not suitable for production environments, but I don't particularly want to utilize a database solely for storing sessions containing flash messages that are deleted immediately after they are displayed. In this particular case, would in-memory session storage be acceptable in the production environment if I am only expecting a maximum of 5 concurrent visitors at a time, or would I still need to configure a database for session storage?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's rather an opinion-based question. For me, it would be fine in a non-commercial or low-traffic project.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Thanks! I just ended up working around it and re-rendering the page with the proper variables depending on the request using custom middleware.